# How to load a model via addressable by setting Remote Catalog Load Path at Runtime in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, addressables

Trying to load an asset using addressable. I have set the build path to Remote build path and load path to Remote Load path.In the manage profile section I have set the remote build path to "https://name-company.github.io/TestProject/[BuildTarget]".Trying to load a 3d model in my app.It is working using the following code by giving the addressable model name here "Panda".

```
AsyncOperationHandle<GameObject> loadWithSingleKeyHandle = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("Panda");
    yield return loadWithSingleKeyHandle;
    if (loadWithSingleKeyHandle.Status == AsyncOperationStatus.Succeeded)
    {
        GameObject obj = loadWithSingleKeyHandle.Result;
        AddressableGO.Add(obj);
        Debug.Log("Prefab Name = " + obj.name);
        Instantiate(obj);         
    }
```

The issue occurs when I try to load from a aws server because random links are generated. I cannot set the remote load path earlier, have to give them  dynamically.[This seems to be the answer](https://forum.unity.com/threads/change-remote-catalog-load-path-at-runtime.712052/#post-4761680).How to set MyApp.Something.URL from the provided link?